# rbenv fails to install ruby 1.8.7 on MacOS X Sierra

Tags: ruby

After creating a `.ruby-version` file with `1.8.7`, running `rbenv install` on the same directory where the file is gives the following error:

> ERROR: This package must be compiled with GCC, but ruby-build couldn't
>   find a suitable `gcc` executable on your system. Please install GCC
>   and try again.
>
> DETAILS: Apple no longer includes the official GCC compiler with Xcode
>   as of version 4.2. Instead, the `gcc` executable is a symlink to
>   `llvm-gcc`, a modified version of GCC which outputs LLVM bytecode.
>
> For most programs the `llvm-gcc` compiler works fine. However,
>   versions of Ruby older than 1.9.3-p125 are incompatible with
>   `llvm-gcc`. To build older versions of Ruby you must have the official
>   GCC compiler installed on your system.
>
> TO FIX THE PROBLEM: Install Homebrew's apple-gcc42 package with this
>   command: brew tap homebrew/dupes ; brew install apple-gcc42
>
> You will need to install the official GCC compiler to build older
>   versions of Ruby even if you have installed Apple's Command Line Tools
>   for Xcode package. The Command Line Tools for Xcode package only
>   includes `llvm-gcc`.
>
> BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.4 using ruby-build 20170405-2-g3b15693)

Then running `brew install apple-gcc42` gives:

> apple-gcc42: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
>   versions newer than Mavericks due to an upstream incompatibility.
>   Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Stuck trying to install ruby 1.8.7 through rbenv on MacOS X Sierra. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Did you post the answer as part of the question?? (Move it into an answer below.)

Comment: Thank you Holger and Tom for your comments. Edited the question to clarify and posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous answer looks good, but some updates for it:

You must add the following code not after line 762 (because from version to version lines must be different).
You must insert it after:

```
require_gcc() {
  local gcc="$(locate_gcc || true)"
```

these lines(for me it was 784 line)

**So full tutorial:**

Found the solution here: http://xibbar.hatenablog.com

http://xibbar.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/04/28/112813

After running it through Google Translate, got to this:

- Find `ruby-build`: `which ruby-build`
- Edit it (in my case): `vim /usr/local/bin/ruby-build`
- Find the lines like these:

  require_gcc() {
    local gcc="$(locate_gcc || true)"
- Add the following code after it:

  ```
  local osx_version="$(osx_version)"
  if [ $osx_version = "1012" ]; then
   return 0
  fi
  ```
- Run:

  ```
  CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=/usr/local --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" rbenv install 1.8.7-p374
  ```

Hope it's useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: http://xibbar.hatenablog.com

After running it through Google Translate, got to this:

- Find `ruby-build`: `which ruby-build`
- Edit it (in my case): `vim /usr/local/bin/ruby-build`
- Add the following code after line 762:

  ```
  local osx_version="$(osx_version)"
  if [ $osx_version = "1012" ]; then
   return 0
  fi
  ```
- Run:

  ```
  CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=/usr/local --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`" rbenv install 1.8.7-p374
  ```

Hope it's useful to others.